# How to Loop using While and Quit after Success

Tags: android

So, I'm on an Ubuntu 13.04 laptop and was wondering how I could loop a command until it succeeds.

I'm trying to loop "adb connect 192.168.1.102:5555" (for connecting to my Android device over wifi) every 5 seconds, but have it quit after it succeeds. I am having trouble with the latter, making it quit after it succeeds. I have the following code so far, but don't know what I need to do to make it quit after it succeeds.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6057217/

I know this could probably be shorter and more efficient, but I am content with everything but making it exit after the command succeeds.

Thanks!
Cole H

Comment: You are resetting `i` to `false` it is an infinite loop! As it is does not make to much sense. Do you want to exit the loop if `adb` successes or something else?

Comment: @edwin I am trying to make it exit if adb connecting to the device succeeds, not if it runs (if I take out the "i=false,true" lines, it just exits even if it fails to connect.)

Comment: Correction, what I meant is that the while condition will always evaluate to true, which is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
i=1
while ! `adb connect 192.168.1.102:5555 >/dev/null 2>&1` ; do
  echo "Attempt $i) adb: Failed to connect!"
  i=$(( i + 1 ))
  echo "  I will try again in 5 seconds"
  sleep 5
done
echo "adb: Connection successful!"
```

The loop should exit if `adb` "successes" or if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, going to try that now. But what I wanted was for it to just try and connect automagically, without any user interaction for stopping it or anything other than running it.

Comment: Also, just quits after I run "sh until.sh". No loop, no output, no nothing.

Comment: Try again with the edits I made. BTW, This script does not need any user interaction after it is started. As I said, if `adb` is successful the script will exit automatically. I made the remark about Ctrl+C just for completeness' sake. Also, you can substitute `echo` with `notify-send` for a more graphical notification.

Comment: Now, it always says it succeeds, even when adb over Wifi is disabled. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp). Also, are you sure you copied my code verbatim?

Comment: I've already grabbed an ADB over WiFi app (ADB Konnect) and all I want to do now is to have something check for it, and keep checking until it succeeds (so say I am building a ROM, I can run this script and have it automatically check, and once the device is on the same WiFi, it pushes the zip to the SDCard). Yes, I have copied your code exactly.